# Where is the jQuery API on `$.`?

Tags: jquery

I saw this somewhere,

For example there is the `each` function to iterate over objects and arrays:

```
$($arr).each(
function(idx)
  {
     //do stuff
  }
);
```

But then there is the format $.each($arr, function);

What is this "`$.`"? Does it have a name?

What else can you do with it?

Comment: Where do you see anything about `$.()`? That is not syntactically valid JavaScript. At any rate, **all** of the jQuery API docs are at http://api.jquery.com. You can find the docs for `$.each()` at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each.

Comment: I redited the question. I meant "$."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### There is no "jQuery API on `$.`"

`$` is an alias to [`jQuery`, which is a function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).<sup>1</sup> In JavaScript, [functions are objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), which (among other things) means that they can have properties. `$.` is the same thing as `jQuery.` — it's simply using the [dot operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) to access a property of the object.

Note that `$.` or `jQuery.` is **completely meaningless** on its own; it's not syntactically valid because no property name follows the period.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Unless you are using [`$.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noconflict/).</sub>

---

To add what I commented originally:

- All of the jQuery API docs can be found at http://api.jquery.com.
- The API docs for `$.each()` are — `*surprise*` — at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, "$" is just an alias for the "jQuery" variable.

```
$('div');
```

is equivalent to

```
jQuery('div');
```

Other javascript frameworks use the "$" as an alias to their main object as well. This is the reason why many people recommend to make "jQuery safe" code this way to avoid naming conflicts:

```
(function ($) {
   // Place jQuery code here
})(jQuery);
```

I case you don't understand the previous code, it's just a self contained function with a parameter named "$" which calls itself by sending the value "jQuery" to the parameter so that you can use the "$" parameter safely without naming conflicts.

You can see all the functions and "properties" that the jQuery object has by using the following link:

http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=jQuery.&go=

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but in jQuery `$` is just shorthand for `jQuery`.  i.e., `$.each()` is the same as `jQuery.each()`.  $, while short and seemingly nonsensical, is still a valid id in javascript, and libraries often override it for their own purposes.